# How to start a new activity inside a linear layout?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have three layout files. one named activity_home and other named activity_main and last one named activity_test.
activity_main is just a simple layout with single textview and a button. activity_test is a single layout file with textview saying hello world.activity_home is like below.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.example.shan.real_connect.widget.RevealFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/conteiner_frame"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

</com.example.shan.real_connect.widget.RevealFrameLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start|bottom">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent">
        <!-- Layout of Drawer -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I want to open my activity_home and load my activity_test into the linear layout called "content_frame" inside activity_home when i click the button in my main activity. How can i do that thing? code of my home.java file also here below.

```
public class Home extends ActionBarActivity implements ViewAnimator.ViewAnimatorListener,View.OnClickListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private List<SlideMenuItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private ContentFragment contentFragment;
    private ViewAnimator viewAnimator;
    private int res = R.drawable.content_music;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        contentFragment = ContentFragment.newInstance(R.drawable.content_music);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, contentFragment)
                .commit();
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(this);


        setActionBar();
        createMenuList();
        viewAnimator = new ViewAnimator<>(this, list, contentFragment, drawerLayout, this);
    }

    private void createMenuList() {
        SlideMenuItem menuItem0 = new SlideMenuItem(ContentFragment.CLOSE, R.drawable.icn_close);
        list.add(menuItem0);
        SlideMenuItem menuItem = new SlideMenuItem(ContentFragment.BUILDING, R.drawable.icn_1);
        list.add(menuItem);
        SlideMenuItem menuItem2 = new SlideMenuItem(ContentFragment.BOOK, R.drawable.icn_2);
        list.add(menuItem2);
        SlideMenuItem menuItem3 = new SlideMenuItem(ContentFragment.PAINT, R.drawable.icn_3);
        list.add(menuItem3);
        SlideMenuItem menuItem4 = new SlideMenuItem(ContentFragment.CASE, R.drawable.icn_4);
        list.add(menuItem4);
        SlideMenuItem menuItem5 = new SlideMenuItem(ContentFragment.SHOP, R.drawable.icn_5);
        list.add(menuItem5);
        SlideMenuItem menuItem6 = new SlideMenuItem(ContentFragment.PARTY, R.drawable.icn_6);
        list.add(menuItem6);
        SlideMenuItem menuItem7 = new SlideMenuItem(ContentFragment.MOVIE, R.drawable.icn_7);
        list.add(menuItem7);
    }


    private void setActionBar() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                toolbar,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
        ) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                linearLayout.removeAllViews();
                linearLayout.invalidate();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                if (slideOffset > 0.6 && linearLayout.getChildCount() == 0)
                    viewAnimator.showMenuContent();
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private ScreenShotable replaceFragment(ScreenShotable screenShotable, int topPosition) {
        //get the top position. it generates unique link according to the clicked view
        this.res = this.res == R.drawable.content_music ? R.drawable.content_films : R.drawable.content_music;
        View view = findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        int finalRadius = Math.max(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
        SupportAnimator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, 0, topPosition, 0, finalRadius);
        animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        animator.setDuration(ViewAnimator.CIRCULAR_REVEAL_ANIMATION_DURATION);

        findViewById(R.id.content_overlay).setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), screenShotable.getBitmap()));
        animator.start();
        ContentFragment contentFragment = ContentFragment.newInstance(this.res);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, contentFragment).commit();
        return contentFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public ScreenShotable onSwitch(Resourceble slideMenuItem, ScreenShotable screenShotable, int position) {
        switch (slideMenuItem.getName()) {
            case ContentFragment.CLOSE:
                return screenShotable;
            default:
                return replaceFragment(screenShotable, position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void disableHomeButton() {
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

    }

    @Override
    public void enableHomeButton() {
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

    }

    @Override
    public void addViewToContainer(View view) {
        linearLayout.addView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            if(v == linearLayout){
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You can't load one activity inside another, but you can load a "fragment"... if you want to share display contents, make the shared elements into a "fragment" that you include in both activities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using activities you need to you fragments, that's what they are meant for.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: can i start a different activity as fragment?

Comment: No, but you can change your activity to be a fragment. Instead of having `public class Home extends ActionBarActivity` you will have something like `public class Home extends Fragment`. Then you will have to implement some methods from the fragment class instead of implementing the one from the activity class.

Comment: after that, can i use that fragment implemented class as same as normal activity which extends view? i mean can i do some sort of normal activities such as set on click listners to the buttons, draw charts on the same class after implementing fragment ?